# Doing mouse hover on a div and keep the div visible

Tags: menu, hover

I have a simple prob (i guess). Im trying to do a simple menu hover with jquery. On hover, the menu should show a div that contains submenus. If i hover the div, the div should stay visible to select the submenu. Otherwise the div should hide. The code that i have is:

```
$("#sub_menu_modelismo").hide();    

$("#menu_modelismo").hover(
  function () {
    $("#sub_menu_modelismo").show('fast');
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#sub_menu_modelismo").hide('fast');
  }
);
```

The div "#sub_menu_modelismo" should stay visible when the mouse is in it.

Tnx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't described exactly what the behavior is doing right now that's wrong!!

From the code you have displayed the first thing that happens is the 'modelismo' div gets hidden. To me it looks like it will never show!!

Comment: Sorry, you're right :/
First im hidding the #Sub_menu_modelismo. When i mousehover the #Menu_modelismo, the #Sub_menu_modelismo shows up. what i want is when it is visible and i mousehover it, is that the #Sub_menu_modelismo stays visible

Comment: Does that mean you're problem is solved or is there still an issue?

Comment: no. what i want is that the div still visible while is hovered. ate the moment the div is not visible when is hovered.
For example:
$("#menu_modelismo").hover(
  function () {
    $("#sub_menu_modelismo").show('fast');
  }, //here it shows the div sub_menu_modelismo when the menu_modelismo is hovered
what i want is when i hover the div sub_menu_modelismo, it holds visible